# Update statement inserts a new row instead of updating

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

My code should just update a single specific row in the table. I used a simple procedure to update a record in the current application as well and it runs without any problem except this case. Every time the query runs, it actually inserts a new row instead of just updating an existing:

So here is my c# code:

```
        try
        {
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.AddRange(vars);
            command.CommandText = "Update" + tableName;

            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            this.GetData(tableName);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

And here is my SQL code (please ingore 'Alter Procedure' statement, I just wanted to get the core script of the procedure):

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[UpdateExpenditureItems]
    (@ID int,
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @IsGroup bit,
    @Parent nvarchar(50),
    @Description nvarchar(50)
    )

    AS

    Begin

--a new inserted row seems to be a result of running IF statement rather than ELSE
    if @Parent != null
        begin
        declare @ParentID int

        set @ParentID = (select ID from ExpenditureItems where Name=@Parent);

        UPDATE ExpenditureItems SET Name =@Name, Parent =@ParentID, [Description] =@Description, IsGroup = @IsGroup WHERE ID=@ID;

        end
    else
        begin
        UPDATE ExpenditureItems SET Name =@Name, [Description] =@Description WHERE ID=@ID
        end
    end
```

I cannot post a screenshot because of the reputation limit...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that current form was inherited from the other and when I pressed the OK button, base class's OK button click event was fired first and then the child.

Solution: either end up with running base class button click event OR use virtual and override to override the base class method.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Parent != null
```

This is not how you check for null in SQL

Change it to:

```
 @Parent is not null
```

Comment: yes, I have changed this, but it does not solve my problem. Still does not work...

Comment: I have run the stored procedure itself from sql server and it worked well. So the problem is with c# code. But what it can be, I have no idea. In all other similar parts of the project it runs perfectly...